# ng-select binding takes time in large list

Tags: angular

I have a list of city, which is obviously too long.

```
     <ng-select *ngIf="addressData.city.list"
      [virtualScroll]="true"
      [items]="addressData.city.list" formControlName="cityId" name="cityId" bindValue="id"
      bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select City">
    </ng-select>
```

Also ngOnInit() I'm creating FormGroup as well as assigning value as below:

```
  ....
  ....
   cityId: new FormControl(this.data.cityId, [], null),
  ....
  ....
```

Please see the behaviour:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zotyfp-5C2MIcZBoMomVuyVEo8a5Bzm5/view?usp=sharing

While other data is getting loaded properly this particular select takes few seconds.

Comment: .... because the list takes a few seconds to load maybe...? Where does the list come from? How and when is it loaded, and how large is it?

Comment: Actually- it is probably this one this.data.cityId that is the culprit..

Comment: If you ask a question, it’s considered polite if you don’t just abandon it but actually respond to follow up comments.